# What is the best way to check if our web page is talking over SSL using protractor or python

Tags: python, selenium, ssl, selenium-webdriver, protractor

In My Application we go ahead and install certificate so that our website can talk over SSL .

Is there a way in protractor to verify if the website is talking over SSL after certificate is installed .

We are using protractor to automate out tests and i never hit the first page where chrome complains the website is not to be trusted.